# Why is memory leak so bad?

Tags: memory, memory-leaks

I know memory leak is bad and I should always free dynamically allocated memory, and having memory leak is bad practice.
My question is why memory leak considered so bad in todays modern operating system with large RAM. I mean to small memory leaks (maybe less than one MB) and not of some really big structures that consume a lot of memory.

Comment: It depends on what your program does. If it runs for a few minutes and then exits, it may not be a problem. If like some of the apps I work on, they may run for years, and restarting them is to be avoided, then even a small memory leak may build up into a significant issue.

Comment: Weird question. You can consider small memory leaks less bad, but ultimately the system or your app will crash :) Either way, a memory leak indicate that there is something not taken care of in the code.

Comment: The thing is, modern OS's get the memory back from the program on termination. Therefore memory leaks are not a bad thing on small programs. It's not like the part of RAM your program used will stay unusable until a reboot. If you have a memory leak, your program will hold on to the memory it once used and this IS A BAD THING! 

Rule of thumb is, if you are testing stuff and writing really small programs, screw memory management, you can have memory leaks. But if you are writing serious code, you MUST implement measures to release dynamically allocated memory.

Answer (score 3):

Memory leaks are bad because your program claims resources and keeps them occupied for its entire lifecycle, even though it does not need them anymore. If you have a static leak the size of X when the program starts and it does not grow over time it's unfortunate, but probably not the end of the world. If you have a leak every time you perform Y, it's a much bigger problem, as the program's memory consumption will continue growing and will eventually take up an unreasonable amount of resources.

Answer (score 2):

A memory leak is bad because it can eat the entire RAM if you implement nothing to prevent this situation.

You don't know how much time user will remain your application or service opened. It might be for minutes, hours, days or even months, and once an user has opened your software, if you didn't implement your software in the right way to prevent memory leaks, you can disturb the user or even crash the OS!

At the end of the day, it's like if your question would be: *why humans need to practice some sport often?*. You may practice sport and your heart will remain healthy for more time, or you can take your own risks...

Memory leaks are **bugs**. You must avoid bugs, thus, you should put your effort to prevent memory leaks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should think about how many memory leaks will be caused because of the small memory leaks after your codes grow larger.

Answer (score 0):

Memory leaks are bad because it indicates that the programmer is not considering all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no simple answer to your question.

Yes, the truth is that there are many apps that you run that come with memory leaks, and yes, usually this is not something the user feels directly, BUT, they say that a good wood worker is tested when looking at the back side of it's work, and a restaurant hygiene by going in to the toilet.

So if you want to test a good programmer / program go to the back side to the places no one looks at.

And if you wan to be a part of a profession where people want to do a good job, than memory leaks should be a concern.